# Margin of error

Tags: standard-error

From where comes the values

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error

```
1.29
0.98
0.82
```

related to the margins of error for CIs : 99%, 95%, 90%?
These are found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error#Calculations_assuming_random_sampling
 at paragraph "Different confidence levels"?

According to the formula, the standard error should be the sample standard deviation divided by the root of the sample size.

It seems that these values represent a fixed standard deviation, but is there a general form when we do not know the standard deviation and thus estimate it from the sample?

I conducted a simulation study. Results of an artificial survey of voter preference for 2 candidates was generated. I get about 3% margin of error. My confidence level was set at 95% and the sample size was 1,000 participants. The preference for candidate B was set between 45-55%.

However, when the preference favors candidate B at 90%, the margin of error is much lower, maybe 2%. Intuitively, it makes sense as there is less variability in the sample proportion.

I do not know how the numbers 1.29, 0.98, and 0.82 apply to margins of error and how to use them for continuous or binary outcomes.

Comment: This is explained at "Termes statistiques et calculs," where it is apparent that $(1.29, 0.98, 0.82) = \sqrt{1/2(1-1/2)}(2.58,1.96,1.64).$  The latter vector will be immediately recognizable by anyone who has ever worked with the standard Normal distribution, while the meaning of the term in the square root will be apparent to those who have seen the Binomial distribution.

Comment: ok so if I understand you confirm that these numbers 1.29 0.98 0.82 are valid for the case where p=0.5 (estimated statistic is 50%) ? It will clearly not be the same if p != 0.5 (I do recognize the 2.58 1.96 1.64 "three sigma rule")

Comment: my point is : is there something special about 0.5? Does it have something to do with pure randomness ? ( as if since , in practice, we don't know the real p (which we want to estimate ), our best choice is to use 50% as random) I would like to know if my intuition is correct. Moreover if I may just add that the example from Wiki is a bit misleading as they refer to a p=0.47 for John Kerry and suddenly appears p=0.5 below (in the formula or STD of binomial)

Comment: $0.5$ is special because the Binomial variance $p(1-p)/n,$ for fixed $n,$ is maximized uniquely at $p=0.5.$  When you don't know $p$ this (therefore) supplies a conservative overestimate of the variance.

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer. Then my intuition  was right however not clearly formulated I guess